# Options besides FormView for data binding web forms

Tags: asp.net

I don't much care for the template rigmarole of the ASP.NET [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf1dk77%28VS.80%29.aspx) web forms control.  It seems the only way to access template defined controls is to 'capture' module level references to the wanted controls in the `ItemCreated` data binding event, for use in other tasks and event handlers.

Ideally I would just like to be able to call set `this.DataSource` and call `this.DataBind` on a page, but only the latter is possible through inheritence, and doesn't achieve any of my normal data binding needs.

What else is there besides the hairy, scary `FormView` control?

Comment: I have to agree with you here. Long ago I stopped using formviews and just handled the crud stuff manually. The formview saves you time in very basic scenarios, but kills you when you want to do something complex. And yes, findcontrol all over the place is fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the DetailsView control which renders a 2 column table to setup a form.  Very uniform control though, so there is limited flexibility if you need that.

Are you looking for all .NET framework or also any OSS or third party?

HTH.

Comment: anything free actually, doesn't even have to be OSS if it works out of the box, but preferably .NET.

Comment: I haven't seen anything better; I'm also frustrated with the lack of form controls, and I'm building one in my Nucleo.NET framework at http://nucleo.codeplex.com, but I haven't finished yet.